# Using the MCT to evaluate the integral of a series

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm studying for my Measure Theory final and I've come across a question that I can't seem to find an answer for.

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ set $E_n:=[n,2n]$ and let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $\sum_{n\geq 1} 2^{-n} \chi_{E_n}$.  Show that $f$ is a well-defined nonnegative $\mathcal{M}$-measurable function and use the MCT to evaluate $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f d\lambda$.

I'm not really sure where to get started on this and I appreciate any help.

Edit:  Problem solved.

Using the definition of Lebesgue integral, MCT and the fact that 
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1}= \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
$$ 
for $|x|<1$ we find that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f d\lambda = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n}n=4.
$$

Thank you for any help, please let me know if my summary contains errors.

Comment: hint: the partial sums are increasing measurable functions

Comment: Okay so $f_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{-i} \chi_{E_n}$ so that $f_n \to f$ and $\lim_n \int_{E_n} f_n d\lambda = \int_{E_n} f d\lambda$? I know the infinite sum of $f$ is 1, but I'm not sure how to deal with the indicator function, or even if it's relevant.

Comment: no, the last equation makes no sense... it's really not necessary to try this

Comment: @brknparticle, you don't need to edit the title of the question to include "*Solved". By accepting the question, a user who comes across this problem will know it's solved since you've already accepted an answer.

Comment: @RobertCardona Okay thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I leave it to you to show that $f$ is a "well-defined nonnegative $\mathcal{M}$-measurable function."

Let $f_n := \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-k} \chi_{[k,2k]}$ be the partial sums of $f$. Then
$$\int f_n \mathop{d\lambda} = \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-k} k.$$
Since $f_1 \le f_2 \le f_3 \le \cdots$, we may apply the MCT to get
$$\int f \mathop{d\lambda} =\int \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n \mathop{d\lambda}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n \mathop{d\lambda}= \sum_{k =1}^\infty 2^{-k}k<\infty.$$
If you want a closed form for the series, take the derivative of the geometric series $\sum_k 2^{-k}$ and see what you get.

Comment: Okay I'm on board with everything now.  It was a lot less complicated than I had originally thought.  I need to keep basic definitions in mind more when I'm solving these types of problems.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The function is well-defined by simple calculus (here you just need to make sure the series converges at each $x\in\mathbb R$).

Clearly $f$ is nonnegative.  Since $f$ is the supremum of the partial sums $\sum _{n\leq k} 2^{-n} \chi_{E_n}$, $k\geq 1$, which are themselves (simple) measurable functions, $f$ is measurable.

Now apply MCT to the sequence of partial sums (which is nondecreasing).

$$\int_{\mathbb R} f d\lambda=\int_{\mathbb R} \sum _{n\geq 1} 2^{-n} \chi_{E_n}=\int_{\mathbb R} \sup_{k\geq 1} \sum _{n\leq k} 2^{-n} \chi_{E_n}=\sup_{k\geq 1} \int_{\mathbb R} \sum _{n\leq k} 2^{-n} \chi_{E_n}=\sup_{k\geq 1} \sum _{n\leq k} \int_{\mathbb R} 2^{-n} \chi_{E_n}$$
$$=\sum _{n\geq 1} \int_{\mathbb R} 2^{-n} \chi_{E_n}$$

Now do some more calculus.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I feel like I understand this type of problem much better now.

Comment: @brknparticle glad I could help. Note the use of linearity of the integral to commute the integral with a finite summation.